# При парализации тестов с помощью testNG классы не раняться в одном потоке

Tags: java, selenium, testng, parallel

testng.xml:

```
<suite name="Default Suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="3">
    <test name="example">
        <classes>
            <class name="ExampleTest"/>
            <class name="ExampleTest2"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

тесты :

```
@Test(singleThreaded = true)
public class ExampleTest {

@Test
public void firstTest() {
    // пелрвый тест
}

@Test
public void secondTest() {
    // второй тест, зависит от прохождения перевого
}
}
```

тесты запускаются в три потока, но первый тест в одном потоке, а второй во втором, соответственно второй валиться так как он завесит от первого
Как паралелить тесты так чтобы все тесты в одном классе ранились в одном потоке?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если тесты зависимы то они должны быть одним тестом .

Просто объедините их

Comment: в таком случае ухудшается читаемость кода и репорта

Comment: зависимые сценарии объединяются в один сценарий. это одно из ключевых правил любого автотестера. паралелить тесты ради читаемости это глупость

Comment: первостепенно - создание стабильного теста